# How to concatenate session values with a space

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I need to concatenate 3 session values Session["First Name"],Session["Middle Name"],Session["Last Name"] with spaces in between.

I tried the following :

```
     Labelname.Text = String.Concat(this.Session["First Name"],"", this.Session["Middle Name"],"", this.Session["Last Name"]);
```

but I get the result as : firstnamemiddlenamelastname

Comment: Because you are not using no space. Replace "" with " ". Or better use string.format

Comment: use `" "` instead of `""`

Answer (score 3):

You are not concatenating spaces, but empty strings.

```
var empty = ""
var space = " "
```

So, you need to change your example:

```
Labelname.Text = String.Concat(this.Session["First Name"]," ", this.Session["Middle Name"]," ", this.Session["Last Name"]);
```

There are other ways to concatenate strings in C#.

Using the `+` operator:

```
 Labelname.Text = this.Session["First Name"] + " " + this.Session["Middle Name"] + " " + this.Session["Last Name"];
```

Using the C# 6 interpolated strings feature:

```
 Labelname.Text = $"{this.Session["First Name"]} {this.Session["Middle Name"]} {this.Session["Last Name"]}";
```

Using `string.Join`:

```
Labelname.Text = string.Join(" ", new []{ this.Session["First Name"], this.Session["Middle Name"], this.Session["Last Name"]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "" with " ".

```
 Labelname.Text = String.Concat(this.Session["First Name"]," ", this.Session["Middle Name"]," ", this.Session["Last Name"]);
```

Other Way:

```
Labelname.Text = this.Session["First Name"].ToString()+" "+ this.Session["Middle Name"].ToString()+" "this.Session["Last Name"]).ToString();
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: @AnitaMathew try other way instead of this way.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use string.format

```
string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", this.Session["First Name"], this.Session["Middle Name"], this.Session["Last Name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using C# v6+

```
var firstName = this.Session["First Name"].ToString();
var middleName = this.Session["Middle Name"].ToString();
var lastName = this.Session["Last Name"].ToString();

Labelname.Text = $"{firstName} {middleName} {lastName}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out with below method.
Labelname.Text = this.Session["First Name"].ToString() + " " + this.Session["Middle Name"].ToString() + " " + this.Session["Last Name"].ToString();